# Что за ошибка "JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1"? Как отладить, если исходников либы нет? Поможет ли CheckJNI?

Tags: android, android-sdk, отладка, android-ndk, jni

Загружаю .so-библиотеку с помощью System.load/System.loadLibrary, через миллисекунды приложение слетает, в LogCat вот это:

> JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1

И больше ничего.

Каковы вообще причины такой ошибки? Как отлаживать, если исходников библиотеки нет, только .so и всё? Можно ли узнать подробную информацию, наподобие detailMessage у Exception в Java?
Вот в Java даже если исключение обработано и в LogCat не идет вся инфа, то я просто брал дебаггер (тот, что в Eclipse) и смотрел в нём. Для С++ возможно ли подобное?
 
Поможет ли CheckJNI?

Либа, к сожалению, проприетарная, связи с автором нет...